# Client hangs up then getting a non empty list from server

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, wcf

I am using a combination of Entity Framework and WCF to provide Data for a client. But for some reason the client hang up (only when result is a non empty list) then calling a simple server function:

```
public List<CardSet> GetCollactions(string 
{
    try
    {
        if (db.Users.Any(x => x.username == username))
        {
            User requestingUser = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.username == username);
            List<CardSet> result = requestingUser.Collections;
            if (result != null)
                return result;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        db.Errors.Add(new Error() { exception = e.Message, innerException = e.InnerException.Message, source = "GetCollection for user '" + username + "'", time = DateTime.Now });
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    return new List<CardSet>();
}
```

On the server the function is perfectly executed, the result for the database is correct. I call the function on the client like this:

```
List<CardSet> collections = client.GetCollactions(username).ToList();
foreach (CardSet collection in collections)
{
    CollectionList.Items.Add(collection.name);
}
```

Edit: Client is a WPF form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must request from service in async manner to avoid client hangs up, First request async data from list in a thread and when data received continued operation in UI thread:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => client.GetCollactions(username).ToList())
.ContinueWith(result =>
{
    foreach (CardSet collection in result.Result)
    {
        CollectionList.Items.Add(collection.name);
    }
},TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

Comment: Your solution fixed the client but i am still not receiving data from the server. I found a post that was closly the same than my problem, they fixed it by adding Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false; to the EF. But this doesn't work for me because then i will get a nullreferenceexception

Comment: Surround the code that makes the network call in a try/catch block and look at the output from the exception, if one is possibly being thrown. Sometimes I find my network calls aren't working due to malformed urls or malformed data sent to the server

Comment: It is surrounded by try catch but don't through an error